# How locate files in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, file

I want to use this https://github.com/TryHardHusky/csgo-sticker-signature-generator for creating custom logos for my site like this:

[image]

To test I've run the original project on my website. In `js/script.js` I changed locating files with absolute 
address on line 222:

```
"assets/", Generator.currentEvent, "/", Generator.$teamSelect.val().toLowerCase().replace(/ /gi, '-'), ".png"
```

to

```
"//tryhardhusky.github.io/csgo-sticker-signature-generator/assets/", Generator.currentEvent, "/", Generator.$teamSelect.val().toLowerCase().replace(/ /gi, '-'), ".png"
```

but this doesn't work. I tried also this:

```
"https://tryhardhusky.github.io/csgo-sticker-signature-generator/assets/", Generator.currentEvent, "/", Generator.$teamSelect.val().toLowerCase().replace(/ /gi, '-'), ".png"
```

but without effect.

Please help how to use custom pngs in this javascript?

Answer (score 0):

In JS, concatenate is the + sign. Try something along these lines:

`"assets/" + Generator.currentEvent + "/" + Generator.$teamSelect.val().toLowerCase().replace(/ /gi, '-') + ".png"`

Comment: i try and without effect

Comment: I don't know what the code you have in there is doing, or even what it is supposed to be doing. The first thing I would do is make sure you can access the file without those variables (copy the entire link), and then add them back in one by one to see where the problem is. That replace() in particular looks troubling.